# Compare quantity of two lists - with a given tolerance

Tags: c#

-> Already Asked at StackOverFlow, but was adviced to post question here! <-

I want to compare two lists, which both can be null, both can contain `0` or more entries.

If the amount matches, there should be some handling for that.
If not, it should be checked if the difference of the amount is covered by the tolerance given.

Here's what I did. Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Note: Null-Check not included in current snipplet. Currently is done earlier in code, but could be part of the asked solution.

```
int tolerableDifference = 5; //example.                
Result success = Result.Valid;

if (listA.Count == listB.Count)
{
  // do whatever is to be done when counts match. 
}
else
{
    // Lists have different length. No match.
    var absDifference = Math.Abs(listA.Count - listB.Count);

    if ((listA.Count - listB.Count) > 0)
    {
        if (absDifference < tolerableDifference)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Difference below Tolerance threshold. Difference: {absDifference}.");
        }
        else
        {
            //Outside tolerance, too less items in listB
            success = Result.Invalid | Result.TooFewItems;
        }
    }
    else if ((listA.Count - listB.Count) < 0)
    {
        if (absDifference < tolerableDifference)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Difference below Tolerance threshold. Difference: {absDifference}.");
        }
        else
        {
            //Outside tolerance, too many items in listB
            success = Result.Invalid | Result.TooManyItems;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review.To help us reviewing your code it would be better if you at least post the entire method. Giving as much code and context as possible will lead to better answers.

Comment: Hi, yes, i know. But i cannot give more code as this is a commercial project with a quite strong NDA. Unfortunately this is the maximum i can provide.

Comment: You don't have to include any internal names and you can also change them (to something else but still meaningful). If this is some generic search then I don't understand how this can be connected in anyway to your project.

Comment: Please take a look at this meta answer: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3801/29371

Comment: Another meta answer: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/696/29371

Comment: While I agree this isn't a great question so far, I get the impression that this is isn't a helper method, but part of a larger method that's doing many different things, which I guess is why the OP can't show the rest of the method. The types of `listA` and `listB` can be deduced and `Result` appears to be an enum, so I'm not sure what additional context you're all looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather obvious improvement is implementing the `absDifference < tolerableDifference` check *once instead of twice*.

Furthermore, using the ternary `?:` operator will make the remainder of the code shorter and easier to read.

The result:

```
int tolerableDifference = 5; //example.
Result success = Result.Valid;

if (listA.Count == listB.Count)
{
    // do whatever is to be done when counts match. 
}
else
{
    var difference = listA.Count - listB.Count;
    var absDifference = Math.Abs(difference);
    if (absDifference < tolerableDifference)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Difference below Tolerance threshold. Difference: {absDifference}.");
    }
    else
    {
        success = difference > 0
            ? Result.Invalid | Result.TooFewItems   //Outside tolerance, too few items in listB
            : Result.Invalid | Result.TooManyItems; //Outside tolerance, too many items in listB
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: You should not answer clearly off-topic questions.

Comment: I think this question is clearly *not* off-topic, and the code could be reviewed (and improved) *just fine*, as I have just shown. The code may be brief but it works, on top of that its functionality is described in both the question text and in code comments. That's my opinion.

Comment: Actually, regardless of how clear it is to understand, it is still a code stub and not functional as it sits and therefore off-topic.

Comment: I was told from StackOverflow to post question here ... Sorry if this is not correct.